# Inconsistent function behavoi in dplyr::mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to use `dplyr::mutate` to add p-values to a dataframe but it's not working and I can't get my head around why.

This works:

```
my_add<-function(x, y) x + y
str(my_add(5, 15))
#> num 20

df <- data.frame(success=c(5,8,4), fail=c(15,13,18))
mutate(df, total=my_add(success, fail))
#>   success fail total
#> 1       5   15    20
#> 2       8   13    21
#>13       4   18    22
```

But this doesn't:

```
my_binom <- function(x, y) binom.test(x, y)$"p.value"
str(my_binom(5, 20))
#> num 0.0414

df <- data.frame(success=c(5,8), total=c(20,21))
mutate(df, p_value=my_binom(success, total))
#>   success total   p_value
#> 1       5    20 0.5810547
#> 2       8    21 0.5810547

df <- data.frame(success=c(5,8,4), total=c(20,21,22))
mutate(df, p_value=my_binom(success, total))
#> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
#>   Evaluation error: incorrect length of 'x'.
```

Both functions take the same input and return a single numeric, so I can't wrap my head around this discrepancy. Can someone enlighten me as to what's going on? Thanks!

Session info:

```
sessionInfo()
#> R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
#> Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
#> Running under: OS X El Capitan 10.11.6
#> 
#> Matrix products: default
#> BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
#> LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
#> 
#> locale:
#> [1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> other attached packages:
#> [1] bindrcpp_0.2 dplyr_0.7.4 
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#>  [1] compiler_3.4.1   magrittr_1.5     assertthat_0.2.0 R6_2.2.2         tools_3.4.1     
#>  [6] glue_1.1.1       tibble_1.3.4     yaml_2.1.14      Rcpp_0.12.14     pkgconfig_2.0.1 
#> [11] rlang_0.1.2      bindr_0.1
```

Comment: One of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40227556/unexpected-values-while-applying-custom-function-in-dplyrmutate) suggests using ```rowwise()```, which seems to solve the problem, but doesn't get me much closer to understanding what's going on

Comment: try inputting 2 vectors into `my_binom`. eg: `my_binom(c(1,2,3),c(4,5,6))`. Is a single value returned? If so, carefully rewrite `my_binom`; it looks like you want it to output a vector the same length as both inputs, rather than a single number.

Comment: So all ```mutate()``` does is feed the specified columns into the specified function, then ```cbind()``` the output? That explains a lot, actually. I assumed it was looping over the rows and making function calls for each. Thanks!

Comment: That's basically correct, yes. `rowwise()` would force the behaviour you were thinking, which is why it worked, but it's much more efficient to vectorise the functions in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mutate(df, p_value = purrr::map2(success, total, my_binom))
```